# Facebook Javascript SDK Getting a blank page after After Accepting App

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I keep getting an error while trying to use the Javascript SDK for a simple login flow.  I must be doing something wrong, but cannot figure it out.  I'm just trying to redirect a user after they accept the app.

Here is what is happening:
User clicks login button, the app dialogue appears (with correct permissions).  They approve the app, then the popup hangs on a blank page with this url: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request.

However, the app is approved, and if I click out of the dialogue and click the login button again, i am correctly redirected, and the app is installed.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<link type="text/css" href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oranienbaum' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

<script>
// Additional JS functions here
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'my_app_id', // App ID
       // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional init code here
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        $('.submit_button').attr("href","gameurll").removeAttr("onClick");
    }
    });
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

  // Facebook Login Function

function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // connected
            window.location = "gameurl";
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    }, {scope:"publish_actions,email,user_relationship_details"});
}

</script>

<a class="submit_button" href="" onclick="login();" >Login</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your help